# Add a string to a string after n seconds in Python

Tags: python

I tried this, but it just waited 10 seconds to print it all out at the same time

```
from time import sleep

print('This is a string. ', end='')
sleep(10)
print('This is another string')
```

Comment: `print('This is a string. ', end='', flush=True)`?

Comment: Eyy, it worked, thx a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try `print('This is a string.', end='', flush=True)`
Else there is a solution using **[ threading.Timer ( delay_time , function ) ]** [here](https://www.codespeedy.com/call-a-function-after-some-interval-in-python/) to solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

You can take n as an input and store in a variable.
and create a list of strings for simplicity.

```
from time import sleep

string1 = 'This is a string.'
string2 = 'This is another string'
arr = [string1,string2]
n = int(input())

for i in arr:
    print(i,end=' ')
    sleep(n)
```